# Why doesn't the aperture change when I turn the ring on my Nikon lens?

Tags: aperture, manual-mode, nikon-d5300

I have a Nikon D5300, and I have a Nikon ED AF Nikkor 70-300mm 1:4-5.6 D lens. I cannot change the aperture manually in the lens — I can't take photos when I turn the ring.

I want to buy a Rokinon 35mm T1.5 cine lens, which is all manual. If I can't change the aperture manually on my camera, does that mean I won't be able to use it at all?

I don't want to buy it if i can't use it, obviously. Can I use an all-manual cine lens on my D5300?

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't the aperture change when I turn the ring on my Nikon lens?

**If you are shooting still images via the viewfinder**

1) Because the lens doesn't actually stop down until just before the picture is taken. The camera meters and focuses with the lens wide open to provide a brighter viewfinder and a shallower depth of field, which assists in focussing.

2) Because when using a Nikon D lens with the D5300, you need to set the aperture ring to the narrowest aperture (the highest f-number) and use the camera's controls to select the aperture setting. The camera will use a lever to stop the lens down the instant before the photo is taken while the mirror is swinging up out of the way.

**If you are shooting still images or video via Live View**

1) Because in the Nikon D3x00 and D5x00 series, as well as many previous entry level DSLRS, the same lever actuates the mirror assembly and the aperture linkage. Once the mirror is up, the aperture can not be changed from the body.

> **Can I use an all-manual cine lens on my D5300?**

If the lens is built to non-AI specifications you can not.

If the lens has a CPU chip that communicates with the camera you *might*.

Answer (score 1):

This model camera expects you to turn the aperture to the maximum and adjust the aperture using the dial on the camera. To be able to use the aperture ring, you have to be in manual mode. This *might* disable the onboard light meter, the manual isn't clear on this point. If you use a non-cpu lens the light meter will be disabled (Nikon D5300 User Guide p 228).

Answer (score 0):

Does the Nikkor lens have a little tab to lock it off at the minimum aperture? When I bought a Nikkor 50mm D for my dad, it needs to be locked at the minimum aperture, because you choose the aperture of those lens on the camera body via the command dials.

I would double-check whether the Rokinon is compatible first. [Page 228 of your manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/BTcII00t9KUv024jW9c13oRqeg68/D5300VRRM_(En)02.pdf) has a list of incompatible lenses spelt out by Nikon. The Rokinon is probably a manual lens, so turning the aperture ring on the lens should change the aperture. You will have to shoot in M mode, and I have no idea what the effect is for the metering.

As a side note, why are you buying a Cine lens for a stills camera? My impression is that they're generally more expensive than a normal lens.

Comment: This cine lens cost about 400dollars, so its not expensive